Hessian matrix negative definite except in a finite number of points
I'm dealing with optimization problems and I have found myself wondering on this statement:

If $f$ is twice differenciable on $\mathcal{D}$ and
its hessian matrix $\mathbf{H}_f$ is negative definite on $\mathcal{D} \backslash D$ and null on $D$ a discrete and finite set of points, then $f$ is strictly concave on $\mathcal{D}$ and $\max_{x\in \mathcal{D}} f$ has one unique solution.

Moreover I have that $\forall x \in D, (\nabla f)(x) \neq 0$.
My "intuition" tells me that as points in D are finitely many, isolated, and not candidate to be a solution, they are not relevant in the uniqueness of the optimum. Nonetheless, as I have not come to a way to prove it formally, I would be very intersted to have a confirmation/refutation of this statement.

It's not really possible for a concave function to fail to be strictly concave only at isolated points; a failure in strict concavity implies that the graph of $f$ contains a non-trivial line segment, and strict concavity would fail locally around all uncountably infinitely many points on said line segment. So, the premise of your question can't really happen. On the other hand, if you know the Hessian of $f$ exists, is negative-semidefinite everywhere, and negative-definite everywhere except a finite (or even countable) set, $f$ must indeed be strictly concave (and at most one maximum).

@TheoBendit thank you very much for your answer and these precisions. I have updated the original question. Can you give me more details on why the fact of the hessian being null only in a finite and countable number of points does not change the fact that f is strictly concave?

What about $f(x) := -x^4$, with $\mathcal D = \mathbb R$ and $D = {0}$ ?

Let me think about the details, Goug. Also, @dohmatob, $-x^4$ is strictly concave.

Since $f$ is twice differentiable on $D$ (I assume it's convex), I don't think this can happen: $f$ is strictly concave except for a finite number of points.
$\nabla f(x) \neq 0 \forall x \in D$, this implies that the unique solution must be on the boundary of D.
